# Building full path to file, which is inside a folder inside the directory of the executing program

Tags: c#, .net, fileinfo, system.io.file

Inside the directory of the .exe, there is a folder called `exports`. I have a method that takes parameters for a directory and filename.

In this case, I want to give the directory as this `exports` folder. The following is the current code:

```
public void saveFile(string dir, string filename)
{
    ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();

    // creating a spreadsheet...

    // now save the file
    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, filename) + ".xlsx");
    pck.Save(file);
    pck.Dispose();
}

// usage of the above method
saveFile(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + @"\exports", "myFileName");
```

This yields an exception: "The given path's format is not supported". How to solve this?

Comment: Soo.. why did you use path.combine inside the method but not outside the method?

Comment: I think I just found the problem by debugging for the result of that. It is actually "...\Debug\myApp.exe\exports\myFileName.xlsx". It is including the filename of the executable as part of the path.

Comment: Check the update to my answer btw, it might save you your next couple of headaches!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` gives the full path to the file  or exe, including the exe name

You cannot then tack a folder name on after it without first removing the exe name

Try using `Path.GetDirectoryName` to remove the filename from the path:

```
var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
folder = Path.Combine(folder, "exports");
```

It is always a good idea to `Directory.CreateDirectory(folder)` before you try to write a file to a folder path you've built. If the folder exists it's a non op, if it doesn't then it will create it. It can create multiple subfolders in one go

Bear in mind also that when installed properly in Program Files, an application doesn't automatically have the right to save files into a subfolder under Program Files. Your code here that saves data alongside the program will likely fail when the program is installed to Program Files